# IntelliJ IDEA: изменение переменной во время отладки

Tags: отладка, java, intellij-idea

Порылся на официальном сайте, нашёл много полезной информации об отладке, но не нашёл как изменить переменную "на лету", как это можно сделать в Eclipse. Даже во время приостановки запущенной программы не все переменные доступны для редактирования.

*Возможно ли изменять переменные, созданные программистом внутри метода, желательно, без приостановки запущенной программы?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные менять можно. Но:

- переменная должна быть в области видимости. Если это не так, то поменять ее нельзя физически. (нельзя поменять значение несуществующей переменной).
- нужно находиться как минимум после объявления переменной (это частный случай вышеописанного).
- переменная не должна быть оптимизированная. В некоторых случаях компилятор видит, что можно выбросить переменную и сгенерировать более простой код. В этом случае поменять значение переменной нельзя (ее не существует).
- программа должна быть поставлена на паузу (как минимум - отлаживаемый поток). Менять на лету конечно можно, но это как ремонтировать двигатель в тот момент, когда он работает в машине. Скорее всего все будет просто сломано. Я думаю, что эклипс либо приостанавливает код на момент замены, либо просто делает отложенную замену.

Comment: Оказалось, что переменной не было в class файле, она была заменена на другую, потому что была она была равна: var1 + 0, а я хотел изменить на var1 + 8, чего сделать не получилось, так как в откомпилированном файле её не было. Изменил в самом начале на var1 + 8, а потом, во время отладки на var1 + 16 и всё получилось! Возможно, в 4-ом пункте так и есть, программа в eclipse сразу после запуска становится такой же, как и в начале, ведь это пока набросок и данные статичны, ну кроме FPS в заголовке, пока его туда вынес. Смена значения занимает около 2-ух секунд, благодаря breakpoint.
Спасибо!